# JSON response from spring REST controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am getting HTTP error code 406 with following error description:

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

My Goal is to get my POJO class in json response. Kindly find my following configurations:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testjson",produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Employee testjson () {
        System.err.println("testing json");
        Employee testEmp = new Employee("1", "Ankit", "Agarwal");

        return testEmp;
    }
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
      <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
           <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
           <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
           <entry key="rss" value="application/rss+xml" />
        </map>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I had added <mvc:annotation-driven/> in spring-servlet.xml and i can see json response with POJO class.

Comment: I had one doubt. I had removed bean ContentNegotiatingViewResolver in spring-servlet.xml and also removed produces="application/json" on RequestMapping. Still i can see json response on this url. Does anybody knows from where its catching that response will be of type json ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testjson",produces="application/json",headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: My only concern is that i removed produces="application/json" in class. Still i am able to get json response. I wanted to know which part of spring does that. Thanks for your response.